# RegEx - MatchCollection get subMatches

Tags: regex

I have a text file like this:

```
Start
<Not Present>

   Start
  <Word>
   End

   Start 
   <Word>
   End

   Start 
   <Antoher>
   End    

End
```

I have to write a regEx that provide as result only "Start...End" blocks that contains `<Word>`.

I've tried with something like this:

```
(Start[\s\S]+?(<Word>.*)[\s\S]+?End)
```

and I get two submatches as result.
First submatch:

```
Start
<Not Present>

   Start
  <Word>
   End
```

Second submatch:

```
   Start 
   <Word>
   End
```

As you can see the second one is correct but the first one is wrong. I want only submatches where `<Word>` is inside a "Start...End" block.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?s)Start(?:(?!Start|End).)*<Word>(?:(?!End).)*End
```

`(?!Start|End).` matches any one character (including `\n`, thanks to the `(?s)` modifier) unless it's the first character of `Start` or `End`.  That makes sure that you're only matching the innermost set of `Start` and `End` delimiters.

I used `.` in Singleline mode (via the inline `(?s)` modifier) to match any character *including linefeed* because you mentioned `MatchCollection`, indicating that you're using the .NET regex flavor.  That `[\s\S]` hack is usually only needed in JavaScript.

---

**CORRECTION:**  I had assumed you were talking about the class `System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection` from the .NET framework, but I've just learned that VBScript also contains a class called `MatchCollection`.  It's probably the VBScript flavor you're using (via ActiveX or COM), so the regex should be:

```
Start(?:(?!Start|End)[\S\s])*<Word>(?:(?!End)[\S\s])*End
```

Sorry about the confusion.  More info available [**here**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html).

Comment: Is it possible that in VB6 I can't use (?s) inline modifier?

Comment: Is VB6 a .NET language?  I can't remember.  If not, it will follow the same rules as VBScript/JavaScript/ECMAScript, and you'll have to use `[\S\s]`.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You are using a "greedy" match - just add a `?` to make it non-greedy. Without this, it will match a `Start` and `End` that spans *two* pairs - the first `Start` and the second `End` - and put it at both the start and the end of `<Word>`
2. The expression `[\s\S]` matches everything - it's the same as a dot `.`. You want just white space `[\s]`

Try this (you can remove the redundant outer brackets too):

```
Start(.*?<Word>.*?)End
```

Comment: The code above is an example... unfortunately only white spaces [\s] is not enough. There could be something like Start<Other><Word>End... How can solve it?

Comment: My regex handles that: `.*?<Word>.*?` means "<Word> anywhere in the input", but non-greedy. I've edited the regex to remove the irrelevant whitespace match too

Answer (score 0):

`[\s\S]` doesn't make much sense. `\s` matches whitespaces and `\S` does the exact opposite - it matches non-whitespaces. So `[\s\S]` is pretty much equivalent to `.`.

I am also unsure what you want to achieve with the `.*` after `<Word>`. That would just match the whitespaces after `<Word>`.

```
(Start[\s]+(<Word>)[\s]+End)
```

As far as I can tell, it works on your test case in http://regexpal.com/.